# get list of file names from FTP

Tags: php, mysql, file, import, ftp

I need to import data from an FTP server. the filenames on the FTP server change according to timestamp. I need to process all files on the FTP server in a PHP MySQL script. how can I fetch the file names and then use them in my import statements.

My Current code for this is:

```
<?php

$source = "DespGoods.csv";
 $target = fopen("DespGoods.csv", "w");

$conn = ftp_connect("ftp.example.com") or die("Could not connect");
 ftp_login($conn,"user","pass");

ftp_fget($conn,$target,$source,FTP_ASCII);

echo "file downloaded.\n";

/********************************/
/* Code at http://legend.ws/blog/tips-tricks/csv-php-mysql-import/
/* Edit the entries below to reflect the appropriate values
/********************************/
$databasehost = "localhost";
$databasename = "dbname";
$databasetable = "dbtable";
$databaseusername ="dbuser;
$databasepassword = "dbpass";
$fieldseparator = ",";
$lineseparator = "\n";
$csvfile = "DespGoods.csv";
/********************************/
/* Would you like to add an ampty field at the beginning of these records?
/* This is useful if you have a table with the first field being an auto_increment integer
/* and the csv file does not have such as empty field before the records.
/* Set 1 for yes and 0 for no. ATTENTION: don't set to 1 if you are not sure.
/* This can dump data in the wrong fields if this extra field does not exist in the table
/********************************/
$addauto = 0;
/********************************/
/* Would you like to save the mysql queries in a file? If yes set $save to 1.
/* Permission on the file should be set to 777. Either upload a sample file through ftp and
/* change the permissions, or execute at the prompt: touch output.sql && chmod 777 output.sql
/********************************/
$save = 0;
$outputfile = "output.sql";
/********************************/


if(!file_exists($csvfile)) {
    echo "File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path.\n";
    exit;
}

$file = fopen($csvfile,"r");

if(!$file) {
    echo "Error opening data file.\n";
    exit;
}

$size = filesize($csvfile);

if(!$size) {
    echo "File is empty.\n";
    exit;
}

$csvcontent = fread($file,$size);

fclose($file);

$con = @mysql_connect($databasehost,$databaseusername,$databasepassword) or die(mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db($databasename) or die(mysql_error());

$lines = 0;
$queries = "";
$linearray = array();

foreach(split($lineseparator,$csvcontent) as $line) {

    $lines++;

    $line = trim($line," \t");

    $line = str_replace("\r","",$line);

    /************************************
    This line escapes the special character. remove it if entries are already escaped in the csv file
    ************************************/
    $line = str_replace("'","\'",$line);
    /*************************************/

    $linearray = explode($fieldseparator,$line);

    $linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);

    if($addauto)
        $query = "insert into $databasetable values('','$linemysql');";
    else
        $query = "insert into $databasetable values('$linemysql');";

    $queries .= $query . "\n";

    @mysql_query($query);
}

@mysql_close($con);

if($save) {

    if(!is_writable($outputfile)) {
        echo "File is not writable, check permissions.\n";
    }

    else {
        $file2 = fopen($outputfile,"w");

        if(!$file2) {
            echo "Error writing to the output file.\n";
        }
        else {
            fwrite($file2,$queries);
            fclose($file2);
        }
    }

}

mysql_close();
>?
```

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Holy cow - if those are real passwords & usernames, you should immediately change them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd run a list/dir command, then parse the response to determine the file names.  See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php